# How to add two arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like this:

```
a = ['a','b','c']

b = ['x','y','z']
```

I am trying to get array like:

```
[['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
```

I have used `array.push` but I am getting like this:

```
['a','b','c','x','y','z']
```

May i know how to solve this?

Comment: How about: `arr = [a,b]`

Answer (score 3):

You can specifically create the new array by passing in both variables to a new array constructor, or by using the `[ ]` shorthand as below:

```
var newArr = [ a, b ];
```

Answer (score 1):

define a variable, c and set it as an array and push both a and b into it. It will do what you are expecting.

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];
var b = ['x','y','z'];

var c=[];
c.push(a);
c.push(b);
```

Here's a working fiddle (Open up the console in chrome [F12]).
http://jsfiddle.net/28MnN/

Comment: +1 for solution that works with a variable number of arrays.

Comment: So will the others...

Comment: @BenM The other solution works only if you know the number of arrays you want. If you have your initial arrays as values in a map, it doesn't work: `for (var key in map) { c.push(map[key]); }`

Comment: Not true. After initially defining the array, you can easily call `ar.rpush()` again...

Answer (score 0):

```
var twodArray=[['a','b','c'],['x','y','z'] ];

or var twodArray=[a,b];
```

Comment: `2dArray` is an invalid variable name. Variable names cannot start with a digit.

Comment: Yeah i forgot that..I just edited

Answer (score 0):

I've added a third variable named `c` which refers to the same array as `a` :

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
var c = a; // a === c
```

Following solution works great, however, after having merged `a` and `b`, any change on `a` won't be reflected on `c` anymore, since `a` and `c` will refer to different objects :

```
a = [a, b]; // a !== c
a.push('something');
console.log(a); // [["a", "b", "c"], ["x", "y", "z"], "something"]
console.log(c); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

This second solution allows to avoid the situation above :

```
a.push(a.splice(0), b); // a === c
a.push('something');
console.log(a); // [["a", "b", "c"], ["x", "y", "z"], "something"]
console.log(c); // [["a", "b", "c"], ["x", "y", "z"], "something"]
```